# Rollback devise invitable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, authentication, devise, devise-invitable

Just made a roll back on a migration that added columns for devise_invitable and deleted the migration. I am now receiving the following error when trying to login to my app.

```
 undefined local variable or method `invitation_token' for #<User:0$%$%$%@@@@@>
```

I cant seem to find invitation_token anywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to remove ':invitable' from the devise callback in your User model. Without the columns, the gem will not work.